# (Java) Como conseguir un input de este estilo

Tags: java, array, matriz

Necesito hacer un codigo que me permita leer el numero de pruebas que se realizarán y luego para cada prueba leer una matriz distinta. No estoy consiguiendo hacerlo con ciclos for.

INPUT:

3

Prueba 1

0 20 10

1 12 34

1 5 6

Prueba 2

0 22 10

1 10 34

0 0 0

Prueba 3

0 10 10

0 0 20

0 0 0

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introducir numero de pruebas realizadas");
    String[] nombre = new String[n];
    int prueba [][]= new int[n][3];
     
    for (int i=0; i < n ; i++ ){
      
        System.out.println("Nombre de la prueba "+i);
      
        nombre[i]= input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introducir valores");
        for (int j=0; j< 3;j++ ){
            int prueba [i][j]= input.nextInt();
        }         

    }        
}
```

Comment: ¿Esto `int prueba [i][j]= input.nextInt();` compila? Dentro del for interno estás volviendo a definir el array prueba, pero dudo que así como está no te de un error de compilación.

Answer (score 0):

El primer problema que veo es que no declaras n en ningún momento. Tampoco haces la operación correspondiente para el input del número de pruebas. El escáner de java suele dar problemas si se utiliza consecutivamente con tipos distintos (int y String en este caso), de este modo, es muy recomendable crear dos escáneres distintos para evitar esto. Una vez corregido aquello, solo quedaría no hacer `int prueba [i][j]= input.nextInt();` ya que estás redefiniendo la matriz prueba. Para terminar, es recomendable cerrar el escáner una vez no lo vayamos a volver a usar. El código con la corrección quedaría así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputInt = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inputString = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introducir numero de pruebas realizadas");
    int n=inputInt.nextInt();
    String[] nombre = new String[n];
    int prueba [][]= new int[n][3];
     
    for (int i=0; i < n ; i++ ){
      
        System.out.println("Nombre de la prueba "+i);
      
        nombre[i]= inputString.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introducir valores");
        for (int j=0; j< 3;j++ ){
            prueba [i][j]= inputInt.nextInt();
        }         

    }   
    inputString.close();
    inputInt.close();
    
}
```

De este modo, el código debería hacer lo que buscas. En caso de querer comprobarlo podrías añadir la siguiente pieza al final del método:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputInt = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inputString = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introducir numero de pruebas realizadas");
    int n=inputInt.nextInt();
    String[] nombre = new String[n];
    int prueba [][]= new int[n][3];
     
    for (int i=0; i < n ; i++ ){
      
        System.out.println("Nombre de la prueba "+i);
      
        nombre[i]= inputString.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introducir valores");
        for (int j=0; j< 3;j++ ){
            prueba [i][j]= inputInt.nextInt();
        }         

    }   
    inputString.close();
    inputInt.close();
    System.out.println("Probamos si se han leído bien los datos");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        System.out.println("Prueba "+i+": "+nombre[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
            System.out.println("Elemento "+j+": "+prueba[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Siendo el input:**

3

primera

12

334

234

segunda

234

26576

8789

nombre cualquiera

234

3456

4567

**Obtienes el siguiente output:**

Probamos si se han leído bien los datos

Prueba 0: primera

Elemento 0: 12

Elemento 1: 334

Elemento 2: 234

Prueba 1: segunda

Elemento 0: 234

Elemento 1: 26576

Elemento 2: 8789

Prueba 2: nombre cualquiera

Elemento 0: 234

Elemento 1: 3456

Elemento 2: 4567

**Espero haberte ayudado.**